# Why are some duplicate questions not closed despite my flags being marked helpful?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, flags

I have flagged many questions on Stack Overflow as duplicate and the flags are dismissed as helpful by a moderator, but the questions are not closed. One example is a question regarding [Android development in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532595/is-it-possible-to-develop-an-android-application-with-c), which is definitely a duplicate of another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443690/is-there-a-way-to-develop-c-net-on-android-devices), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371939/how-can-i-use-ms-visual-studio-for-android-development), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214615/will-google-android-ever-support-net).

Comment: Sometimes a moderator will mark your flag as helpful even if they decide not to act on it.

Comment: My question is why ? I understand that deleting a duplicate question is not a good idea because they can act as "Flag bearers" to an existing question, but why not close them ?

Comment: It turns out the system automatically cleared your flag (as helpful) when someone cast an actual close vote to the question.

Comment: So isn't that a duplicate question ?

Comment: It is a dupe, but it takes 5 users (3 more, in this case) to vote it so.  Apparently if we vote from within the 10K tools to close it, it clears the close-vote flag, but the question is still 1 vote closer to doom. ;)

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ That would be the answer to what asked here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does flag marking as helpful/declined not always correlate with moderator action?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105391/why-does-flag-marking-as-helpful-declined-not-always-correlate-with-moderator-ac)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I often mark a flag as "useful" because I can understand *why* the flagger flagged it, but ultimately I disagree with the flag.

For example, if I see a question linking to a dupe, and it's pretty close but not close enough, I still mark it as helpful because they had a pretty valid point, and I don't want to discourage them from further flagging - even though I'm not going to action the flag.