# Why is the auto generated duplicate comment disappearance not consistent?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, comments, duplicate-questions

I have flagged the following two questions as duplicates:

- [Split list based on element value in Scala [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65169480/2359227)
- [The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. - Laravel [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64222428/2359227)

After flagging, both generated a comment from me in the shape:

> Does this answer your question? [canonical link](https://Link to duplicate)

Both flags were marked as helpful (screenshots below), and in both questions, the post notice appeared:

> ### This question already has answers here:
>
> [canonical link](https://Link to duplicate)

So far, both are the same. But in the first link I attached, the comment was removed once it was marked as duplicate, and in the other, the comment is still there.

Why is that?

[image: Post 2 was marked as helpful]

[image: Auto comment not deleted]

Note: this exact behavior was reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339888/152859) as an answer to the new post notices announcement, marked as [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) under [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review), but forgotten since then.

Comment: No one reviewed your flag on the post where your comment still is.  That's why it remains.

Comment: @Ollie what do you mean? If it wasn't reviewed how come it is marked as duplicate?

Comment: Because someone else closed it.

Comment: Maybe I don't know what do you mean by review. The flag was marked as helpful. Didn't that happen while someone reviewed it?

Comment: Funny.  It may take a minute to get you an answer, I don't have much reputation on SO.

Comment: I still think the review might have something to do with it.  See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116385/798831).  And then it might have been closed by a user with a tag badge.

Comment: [Also](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116308/why-are-some-duplicate-questions-not-closed-despite-my-flags-being-marked-helpfu#comment303923_116308).

Comment: @Ollie _"And then it might have been closed by a user with a tag badge"_ Nope, it was closed by three users, none of them is a gold-badge holder. Also, I don't think that would make a difference. The comment should be removed regardless. At least that's what happens with comments generated by close votes (as opposed to flags) so long as the comment is not edited.

Comment: You're not listed as one of the close voters on that second question. Did you manually add the comment, and not vote to close?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm The OP doesn't have the "Cast close & reopen votes" privilege. He/she _flagged_ the question (at least according to this post).

Comment: That is correct. I don't have this privilege. I flagged this post. I added screenshot of the flag that is marked as helpful.

Comment: Might be a one time glitch, did you ever notice this on other questions?

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard, it is not a one time glitch. Here is another example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64642380/how-to-mock-a-function-to-return-a-dummy-value-in-scala

Comment: Worth adding this to the question too. And I see both comments have high score of 5, so my best guess for now is that if such auto comment gets score of 5 (or 4? or 3?) it won't get auto deleted, which might even be by design: don't auto delete something that might be useful.

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard, I found one with score 1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63854516/how-to-get-typesafe-activator-1-3-6-on-mac . And the example I sent had a score of at least 2, so I guess it is not related. Although thought so as well in the beginning.

Comment: @TomerShetah My best bet would be that https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339888/369802 was never fixed, and the comment that was deleted, was deleted manually because it was flagged as no-longer-needed. Only a SO mod can confirm that though...

Comment: I've asked ChrisF to take a look... it's not as simple as I just said. The comment on your first example was deleted by the Community user, which suggests that it was indeed automatically deleted, and not because people flagged it . It does still seem like it may be related to the post I just linked, just that it's not as consistent as I thought it might be.

Comment: This will be addressed as part of our bug duty rotation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This bug has been fixed for future flags - this was a fun one to look into, thanks for the report! Any new Close Flags created after today (January 31, 2022 at 17:00 UTC) will now handle this correctly. Any flags and explanatory comments created before today will still exhibit this behavior as no backfill was done. If you still see orphaned explanatory comments that are created after these changes, please create a new post with a link to the question you're seeing this on.

---

When a post is flagged as a duplicate, an explanatory comment is created and associated with the flag. Later, when the flag is cleared, the explanatory comment associated with it is removed.

The explanatory comment was generated with a Recommend Close Flag. Then, another user later flagged the post with a Close Flag. This cleared the Recommend Close Flag and upvoted the explanatory comment. However, this new Close Flag did not have an explanatory comment associated with it beyond the user upvoting it.

Later, when the Close Flag was successful, our code would look at any active flags and remove explanatory comments associated with those flags. Since the new Close Flag had no associated explanatory comment, it would fail to remove it.

Now, the explanatory comment is handed off when a Recommend Close Flag is superseded by a Close Flag and will get removed appropriately.

Answer (score 5):

I think (and this is only speculation) that the difference is that the last close vote on the first question was cast by Community. This means that the OP agreed to the duplicate suggestion, which closed the question. In the second case the question was closed by three users voting to close as a duplicate of the suggested target.

As to why this would delete the comment on the first question and not the second, I've no idea. I will probably need someone with more access than me to determine exactly what's gone on here.

Comment: Thanks ChrisF for the speculation! That makes sense actually! Please let me know if you can confirm this theory!

Comment: This is the most plausible explanation. I think it's still a bug though because that's not consistent with comments generated by close votes (which always get removed, unless edited before the closure).

Comment: @TomerShetah I haven't had chance to look at this again, sorry. If I see a CM online sometime soon I'll ask them if someone can take a look.

Answer (score 5):

This bug is still present today. Another example can be found [on this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362001/can-moderators-please-be-more-careful-when-marking-questions-as-a-duplicate).

In this case the [suggestion done by ChrisF](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357571/361484) does not apply, as the question was closed using a binding vote by a goldbadge wielder.

Screenshot in case someone deletes the comment:
[image]