# How to remove duplicate answer (Flagging for moderator attention is also not working correctly)

Tags: discussion, flags, moderators, duplicate-answers

My question is how to remove duplicate answers, I mean many users just copy the correct answer and post it as their own without even knowing what they have posted. So how can I remove these answers which are exact duplicates of old answers without any modification.
For reference take this case-
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175012/mysql-query-to-count-white-spaces-or-words-from-entire-row/10175598#10175598)

There are so many available answers for this question but they have only one answer-flag for moderator attention.

I have flagged it and moderator found it useful, screenshot of it is as

[image]

Even one answer's code is also not correct because he removed ` from my code which made it full of error.

Now my question is if the moderator accepted these two flags then why aren't these duplicate answers removed?

Comment: Did you consider that, since the answer in question is just a single line of bog-standard SQL code, two people could have independently posted the exact same answer to the question?

Comment: But the last two answers are just copy paste of my answer, nothing new in them

Comment: Obviously you *still* haven't considered that... And let's try to tone down the accusations, eh? It's fairly offensive to accuse people of copy-pasting your answer **without any evidence** that they've actually done so. The fact that the answers are similar does not count as evidence.

Comment: @TheEstablishment but you can see the screen shot that moderator is also agree to me.

Comment: No, they just marked your flag as helpful. That doesn't mean that they *agree* the answers were duplicates. They were probably hoping to keep you from running to Meta [complaining that your flag was declined](http://i.stack.imgur.com/An1s1.png). Oh well, live and learn.

Comment: @jason not all helpful flags garner action

Comment: @simchona then what is the profit to mark them helpful if they didnot deserve an action.

Comment: Mods mark flags as helpful even if they're not going to take action. Since I'm not a mod I can't say what they're thinking, but I hazard the guess that they said it was helpful, looked into it, and did what they thought best.

Comment: Wow, it's like my comments don't even get read. The next question is inevitably something I *just* answered.

Comment: @theestablishment I'm reading them.

Comment: It's getting difficult to understand your English. If you're not going to consider what I or @theestablishment said, I'm not wasting my time fighting with you.

Comment: @TheEstablishment but this attitude is wrong if the flag is marked as helpful just to remove the chance of further cumplain'

Comment: I see. I'll let all the SO moderators know to mark your flags as "declined" from now on.

Comment: @jason then that's a different question. You might want to know that The Establishment is a mod. He knows things.

Comment: @simchona i didnot interested to know if establishment is a mod or not, i am just want the exect reason for this topic, thats it......and i didnot want to fight at all and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @TheEstablishment i have faith in the other mod's :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is that answer even correct? I'm not a MySQL expert, but I do know "from" is a reserved key word, and I'm not sure if that query will run with the word not enclosed in backticks like that.

Anyways, moderators aren't *required* to take action on a flag. They can dismiss flags as helpful and they're actually [encouraged to do so in cases where the user was legitimately attempting to be helpful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105391/why-does-flag-marking-as-helpful-declined-not-always-correlate-with-moderator-ac).

As for duplicated content, it is a very borderline issue. Likely the moderator who reviewed your flag didn't feel comfortable deleting the post.

Comment: In my answer i am using `` in from but the other poster doesnot done that he just copied my answer and removed ` without even understanding the real fact of using `

Comment: @jason stop making accusations. Simple code can be thought of independently.

Comment: @simchona yes i know that simple and even complicated code can be though independently but the syntex is exect duplicate in this case and i didnot think it as a coincident.

Comment: @jason the syntax is rather hard to deviate from.

Comment: @simchona a have not answerd that question that fast , i have done tha similar question previously and i have took too much time to reach on the exect code, so i didnot think the other two have done any hard work to do so because one answer is juct appear after mine and is must not be a coincident

Comment: @jason So because you think you thought of it first, they didn't do any hard work? Your answer got accepted. What's the issue?

Comment: @simchona issue is that how to remove duplicte answer? as you can read it in title

Comment: They're not necessarily duplicates of *your* answer. It's not illegal to have similar code. Deal with it.

Comment: You might be interested in reading up on the *cum hoc ergo propter hoc* logical fallacy. This is where one assumes that because two events have a temporal relationship, that one caused or is related to the other. That's what happened here: two people posted similar answers to a question on Stack Overflow, and you're committing a logical fallacy by assuming/accusing them of having copied your answer just because you both posted it within a similar period of time. You might also consider *getting on with your life*.

Comment: @The: ***post*** _hoc ergo..._

Comment: YES YOU'RE RIGHT IT TURNS OUT THAT THE ENTIRE STACK OVERFLOW SYSTEM IS BROKEN BECAUSE A "DUPLICATE" ANSWER WAS NOT DELETED. WHAT HAPPENED TO YOU HERE HAS OPENED UP A WORMHOLE IN THE UNIVERSE. COLLAPSE IS IMMINENT. RUN FOR THE HILLS!!

Comment: @jason Duplicate questions have a wide gap of time when one is clearly linked to the other. Duplicate answers is based on the assumption that the answers are actually duplicates. Which doesn't seem to be true here.

Comment: @simchona thanx for talking time for polite conversation. Now i got my answer.