# Why didn't my helpful flag result in the reopening of my question?

Tags: discussion, flags, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

Some days ago, I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382610/do-compiler-warnings-indicate-undefined-behavior) which got 4 down votes and further put on hold by mr. [minitech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) citing the reason that it was too broad and answers would be apparently very long not suitable for this platform.

I tried to improve the question, and made it more specific and then I raised a flag. The flag was marked **helpful** but question didn't reopen.

I don't quite understand how will it reopen, I assume that some moderators will vote to reopen it, but why? I guess they don't have that much time.

What should I do now? One guy suggested me to delete my question but I have read that deleted post move towards an automatic ban.

Just locked, shocked and stuck. I would appreciate if anyone helps me out.

Comment: helpful != actioned

Comment: @CodyGray I beg your pardon but what does "actioned" equal to ? What should I do in that case?

Comment: A flag can be marked helpful without any action being taken (e.g. to re-open the question). Helpful just means that the flag was not invalid or useless.

Comment: More specifically, reading the title, I still thought that this question was "too broad". But reading the body of the question, it seems you're asking something very specific: why do I get the same warning for both of these samples of code, when one is very clearly wrong/undefined behavior, and the other is perfectly acceptable. I voted to re-open, but I think the title could still use some work, if nothing else to prevent people from having the same mistaken initial impression that I did.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't think it makes any sense, I made a flag for reopening of question and it was considered helpful but I would apparently get no benefits of it? Ok , Then I should better try to improve the title isn't it ? And thanks for the vote :)

Comment: Similar: [Why does flag marking as helpful/declined not always correlate with moderator action?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105391/why-does-flag-marking-as-helpful-declined-not-always-correlate-with-moderator-ac)