# Reasons for keeping Off-Topic question

Tags: discussion, flags

I recently flagged a question as off-topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343044/how-to-delete-a-msmm-exe-virus-from-windows-xp and my flag was marked as "Helpful" yet the question still exists and hasn't been transferred to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) and/or burninated.[image: Flag Snippet]

So, I have several questions pertaining to flagging:

314159. If an event such as this happens, should I go back and reflag as "Needs Moderator Attention"?
314160. When is it appropriate to flag a question?  Is it appropriate to flag it even if there is/are one/several answers?  What if there is an accepted answer?  What if the question has one/several upvotes?
314161. Are there any valid reasons for this question to still exist?
314162. Is there a generally-accepted un-written-about "age" of questions that should be left as-is and not flagged as to not clog the queues (i.e. anything older than 1 year/6 months/7 days)?

Comment: It gets marked helpful as soon as anybody casts a close vote on it. Currently there's only 1 of the 5 votes needed to close/migrate it.

Comment: Just FYI for those reading; I just now closed it. Before I did that, it had one vote to close, as @Mysticial notes above.

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105395/147247 - third bullet of the answer covers this case

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. No.  You already told us about it.
2. You don't have to evaluate the answers to flag a question.
3. It should stay on the site long enough for the OP to see that it was closed (it becomes eligible for deletion by the community in two days).
4. No.