# Reputation loss with a spam or offensive flags

Tags: feature-request, reputation, flags, spam, penalty

As the help page says:

> **You lose reputation when:**
>   One of your posts receives 6 spam or offensive flags:−100

I think this should be changed. This means that in less popular tag posts this is more difficult to happen, which shouldn't interfere.

Moreover, when someone flags something as spam or offensive, and gets flag-reviewed, if its valid it will probably be deleted, and this will interfere in less popular tag posts as said before, as it won't be flagged again.

---

I think that if an offensive or spam flag is accepted the penalty should apply (**only with one**, maybe the reputation loss in this way should be less). Or maybe we can apply a penaly by a number of posts flagged that way in a period of time.

**EDIT:**
As you can see in the comments in Richard answer, the thing that I'm talking about is already contemplated: With only one flag (for example), if it's moderator-reviewed (and valid), the penalty is applied. Maybe this information should be included.

Sorry if I explained myself bad. Thought that if a spam or innapropiate flag were reviewed before the count reaches 5 more, then the penalty was not applied.

Comment: -100 is totally reasonable penalty in my opinion. No need to change anything.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd See emphasis. The change is not about reputation, is about the conditions. I propose the reputation loss with only one flag (per post).

Comment: It would need 6 spam or offensive flags. 6! That's not something you stumble into. "Ah yeah, I insulted you to the core there. Sorry. Cat ran over my keyboard. Random characters really". Nah, it seems just fine to me.

Comment: @Bart Most spam or offensive flags I made were removed fast (the flagged post), and the user didn't suffer a penalty because of it.

Comment: Your point being?

Comment: @SysDragon, it looks like you want to ensure *all* spam/offensive posts incur the penalty. The impact will probably not be that important (e.g. -100 rep is no deterrent to actual spammers, who will just create another account).

Comment: Most spam posts are from low-rep users who are destroyed anyway.

Comment: So I'm even more against it. One or two spam flags might be a mistake. Only 6 can assure (as far as "sure" can be achieved) it's really a spam post.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That's why I said that the penalty apply only when the flag is reviewed and it's valid.

Comment: @SysDragon in case of one spam flag and three "not an answer" flags when moderator approves **all flags are becoming valid**. So...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Now it's clear, thanks. I edited my question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Spam flags are ultimately flags to a moderator. If 6 users spam flag the post then it short cuts and just deletes the post. But, if 6 flags are not achieved a mod will review the flag.

As such it's not necessary to adjust the numbers based on the tag size. If the mod agrees it's spam it will get the -100 penalty, if it's not spam then it shouldn't get that penalty.

Comment: But the moderator won't apply a rep penalty for, for example, insulting. The post will be simply deleted. Isn't it?

Comment: @SysDragon If it's a spam flag and the moderator validates it as spam then it will be treated as spam. With all the usual penaties

Comment: Yes and no. If a moderator agrees with the flags (he can choose between either all flags or no flags) the penality is there. If he disagrees, he then no penality is done. - This is a problem if 1 user cast a spam flag on an insulting post and the mod does not feel like it is spam -> all flags are declined, otherwise the user get the -100 rep penality.

Comment: I talked about the opposite: a spam flag on a non-spam post.

Comment: but if it's not spam it **shouldn't** get the -100 penalty

Comment: Right, and therefore mods decline **all** flags. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105391/why-does-flag-marking-as-helpful-declined-not-always-correlate-with-moderator-ac

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Then the thing that I'm asking for is contempled already. Then maybe the information should include that, to be clear =/

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I agree that is a problem, but not in this case. As the most harsh flag a valid spam flag won't suffer from this