# Could a flag status change? (revisited)

Tags: support, flags, helpful-flags

Yet another flag status question...

However I've read that:

1. > A flag's status **will never change** once it has been set.
   >
   > ---
   >
   > From: [Can I get rid of “disputed” flag stat, if it turned out to be correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212511/304899)

And I've also found that when:

2. > A spam or "rude or abusive" flag is cleared (but not declined) by a moderator [results] in a flag being disputed.
   >   [...]
   >   This can also be done retroactively, in which case **the outcome will change** from helpful to disputed. <sup>**(*)**</sup>
   >
   > ---
   >
   > From: [What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95277/304899)
   >   <sub>**(*)** Notice this was recently [edited in by an anonymous user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/50545) .</sub>

So, which is it?

- Was there a change in this behaviour?
- Provided the status could actually change, how exactly is it that it's done retroactively? Does it mean a moderator is allowed to change spam/abusive flag from *helpful* to *cleared*?
- Are there any other paths where a flag status would be modified after it has been set?

Comment: related: [Can a declined flag be made helpful flag later by Moderator?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343467/839601) "No actions will change the status... Except for *spam* and *rude-or-offensive* flags; because these flags can incur a 100 point penalty to the author and apply anti-spam measures to an account, moderators can mark *all* such flags on a post as 'disputed' (regardless of their current state). Once such flags are marked disputed, they can't then again be changed to helpful or rejected."

Comment: @gnat That's it, thank you. I believe that answers my question completely.

Comment: duplicate is at another site (MSO) - no way to close

Comment: I've just edited that answer to include this information. It can now be marked as duplicate.