# How can a flag be helpful without any action taken?

Tags: discussion

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/191757/69537) to be duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64782/69537) and my report was marked as helpful:

[image]

But I do not see any action taken. I suppose the duplicate question should be closed. Then how is the flagged question still open if my report was helpful?

Comment: What is the sound of one hand clapping?

Comment: @Rosinante It is the soundless sound of the universe, the being of non-being of all that exist. Koans are employed to make one see that which is from another perspective than that which the one is accustomed to using. Such provides a shift in consciousness so as to create momentary awareness and a glimpse into the true nature of reality. If you continue to seek answers from others you will never find "your" answers.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Casting close votes requires 3k rep, while I have got only 2340 as of today.

Answer (score 7):

Duplicate flags are flags to 3k+ users (as are all closure flags). But it requires at least 5 such users to vote to close.

Such a flag is marked helpful as soon as one duplicate vote is recieved. However, in this case that vote seems to have aged away without the question being closed as there are currently no close votes on the question.

All the reasons when a flag can be marked as helpful without an action being taken are outlined in the question: [Why does flag marking as helpful/declined not always correlate with moderator action?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105391/why-does-flag-marking-as-helpful-declined-not-always-correlate-with-moderator-ac). In this case it was:

> Another user voted to close the flagged question if your flag was a
>   recommend closure flag. This will mark your flag as helpful, but if
>   you can't see close votes it will appear that nothing has happened
>   until the question is actually closed.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to your specific scenario, there are other cases where a flag can be marked as helpful even if no action was taken. For example, I am a moderator on DBA.se and I have marked flagged as helpful in these situations:

1. a flag has notified me of some behavior that I don't need to act on, but perhaps make a note of for later in case the behavior repeats. If doesn't always justify immediate action.
2. a flag as a duplicate or for migration is accompanied by close votes of the same type. In some of these cases I'd rather let the community continue to decide rather than make a binding decision. Not as a cop-out, but because I still want the community to decide how the community should work, when it makes sense for them to do so. Especially in cases where I am not familiar enough with the topic to truly determine, on my own, whether two questions really are identical. I can usually tell with SQL Server, but not so much with Oracle or MySQL.