# Flag helpful but no action taken on tag war

Tags: discussion, tags, flags, moderators, helpful-flags

In regards to https://stackoverflow.com/q/21650114/1348195

I left a comment suggesting that the author should re-tag his question after he went into a ['tag war'](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21650114/revisions) with another high-rep user on the site. (I've corrected it once only to notice the ongoing tag-war later).

After the user responded (misunderstanding the issue), we exchanged a few more messages where I politely (in retrospect it was kind of snarky) tried to explain that the [mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc) tag is completely inappropriate for that question and he will get a lot less likely relevant traffic and more irrelevant traffic.

Eventually, I invited him into a chat room offering to explain how he could use the system better (he didn't join) and flagged the post for a mod to take care of the tagging issue.

[image: The user is insisting to tag his question incorrectly. Me and another user who are more familiar with this website have removed the tag and explained the problem but the user did not consider reading the tagging recommendations or accepting the re-tag]

My flag was marked "Helpful" however the moderator did not re-tag the question. They deleted all the comments (which I get, they were meta comments) but did not change the tag.

#### I wanted to ask *why* the tag was not changed? Was I wrong in flagging the mod?

---

By the way - I can totally see the rationale from a moderation stand point to *not* engage with the user and re-tag their question which might come off as hostility. I wanted to know if an action was taken or if the user was asked to reconsider. Mainly because I want to know what to do in such future cases.

I'm also aware of and read [Why does flag marking as helpful/declined not always correlate with moderator action?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105391/210016) . This question is about specifically re-tagging and what mods can and/or should do in this case.

---

(By the way, since I invited him to chat a room was created - here is [a partial segment of the exchange](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/47098?m=14594311#14594311) it is not the whole exchange but it should get the point across).

Comment: The [rationale](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105391) for retags is the same as that of any other moderator action.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I linked to that question already in this one :) Please see the second section of this question. I'm asking what I should do in the future and what mods can/should do in the specific case of a "tag war" (or to a greater extent an "edit war") so I can act more correctly in the future.

Comment: We don't treat those flags any differently.  Your flag may still be deemed to have merit, even if we don't take any action.  Do you want an answer to your question that focuses on how we deal with retagging, divorced of the valid/invalid dynamic?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Honestly? I mainly want to do what the correct course of action should be in the future. Other than that I'm interested in why it's still wrongly tagged.

Comment: Well, I looked at the comments on the original question.  Big waste of time.  If the guy says it's about MVC, then it's probably an MVC project, no matter how irrelevant you think the tag is.  At least he didn't tag it [potatoes] because that's what he was eating when he posted the question.

Comment: FWIW, moderators generally favor the OP in disputes like this if the tag (or other disputed material) isn't actively harmful to the site, which it doesn't appear to be here.

Comment: That question quite obviously has nothing at all to do with MVC.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't understand the point you were trying to make in third to last comment (is it that OP decides on relevance of tags over users?), would you mind elaborating on that? I admit that I'm sleep deprived at this point though so that might be the reason, thanks for sticking around and explaining the rationale :)

Comment: Um and now it's just been outright deleted. Why?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I solved the problem.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: By removing content created and submitted by three dedicated SO users. That seems somewhat unfair and not the proper way to resolve a question tagging dispute. My 2p. Further, this question has not been answered by this act! :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think we all (mostly) agree that that question was not of oustanding quality. However - to me the problem here was not 'that question is not of oustanding quality' in this case. It is "I'm unsure how to use the flagging system here and what should resolution be in this case".

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: In general, mods prefer to get involved in issues that require a moderator.  This one didn't; in the same manner that mods don't evaluate the veracity of technical content, nor do they get involved with tag disputes unless it's clear that the tag is damaging the site.  MVC is a perfectly valid tag, and if the OP insists that their question has something to do with MVC, who am I to say otherwise?

Comment: In my opinion, what OP thinks is not really relevant. Otherwise, those [election candidates](http://stackoverflow.com/election/5) talking about cleaning up the `xcode` tag would be wrong too. If OP is programming in xcode, and insists that their question has something to do with xcode, then they should be right to tag it like that, right? — But no, that’s not what should happen. Tags are used to categorize questions into meaningful categories useful to organize SO. And that does not necessarily means to agree with OP.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, for one you were elected by the community and entrusted by the administration to make those _exact_ decisions. Especially since in this case (an edit/tag war) mods have both the leverage as a diamond user and the tools to take action where normal users do not. I'm not criticizing the decision that was made here - I'm trying to understand the rationale. If the policy is "moderators usually do not intervene with flags users strongly feel about even if those flags are very likely incorrect" that's also fine and that could be an answer (to this question).

Comment: To put it another way, if the OP had tagged the post [potatoes], I would have removed it without hesitation.

Comment: That being said, I think the retagging war went far too far already. On wikis, you usually have a 1-revert policy telling you to revert just once. If you then can’t fix the issue by discussing it, get a mod to help you. And that mod should decide for the greater good of the site, which in this case would be clearly to choose the proper tags, disagreeing with OP.

Comment: How many people were getting drawn into that question in error because it had the tag [MVC] on it?  A bad xcode tag is not at all the same thing.

Comment: @poke that sounds like a perfectly good answer expressing an opinion (and a very reasonable one) in this discussion. Please consider posting it. You and Robert are both making good points and I'm learning but I think it would benefit everyone more if they were in the form of answers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It is really just the same principle; just that the xcode tag is more messy than the MVC tag because more people are using it incorrectly. Does this mean that we should allow using incorrect tags just because those tags are less abused? Absolutely not, because otherwise they will just end up becoming the new xcode tags.

Comment: @poke, some would disagree that the MVC tag is *less* messy than the Xcode tag.  Both have their uses, and both are *horribly* abused to the point where they're often meaningless...

Comment: Also, about the MVC tag several users (including teresko who participated in that 'tag war' are making a _tremendous_ effort to make that tag clean). It doesn't stay clean on its own.

Comment: Then make a meta post about the MVC tag, asking for a cleanup, since that is the real issue.  You guys took your eye off the ball.

Comment: Great.  12,000 questions with that tag.  See why I don't get involved in tag disputes?

Comment: @RobertHarvey the ball here isn't the mvc tag, or the xcode tag - it's the policy I (and other users) should take in this case. Was I wrong to flag and what were the reasons the flag was deemed helpful but the post was not locked and no comment was left? That's what I'm asking here . http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220388/flag-helpful-but-no-action-taken-on-tag-war?noredirect=1#comment714431_220388

Comment: No, you weren't wrong; your flag was dismissed as helpful.  But... 12,000 questions tagged MVC?  Game over. Time to focus on something that we can actually do something about.

Comment: @RobertHarvey so the rationale was that the mvc tag is doomed and that no action should be taken because it's already a 'lost cause'? (Again, sorry if I'm being daft, still missing that sleep :))

Comment: I can't speak for the personal motivations of the mod who actually dismissed your flag. I can tell you I probably would have taken the same action, for reasons which I've already described in detail.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ok, thanks for the insight - while I don't understand or agree with some of the rationale - it has been helpful to learn about.

Answer (score 10):

*(Converting my comments into an answer)*

In my opinion, what OP thinks a question should be tagged with is not really relevant. Sure, they are asking the question, so they can (and should) already set up a good selection of tags to make sure their question is categorized properly and gets the correct attention. But in general, we can’t expect posters to know what the correct tag usage is.

If we instead would just agree with what OP thinks, then [those election candidates](https://stackoverflow.com/election/5) talking about cleaning up [xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode) would be just wrong too. If OP is programming in xcode, and insists that their question has something to do with xcode, then they should be right to tag it like that, right?

But no, that’s absolutely not what should happen. Tags are used to categorize questions into meaningful categories with the primary purpose to organize SO. And that does not necessarily means to agree with OP, especially since OP’s main concern is probably to get their question answered but not to make sure that the question will be valuable forever.

That being said, I think the retagging war went far too far already. On wikis, you usually have a “1-revert policy” (or similar) telling you to revert just once. If you then can’t solve the issue by discussing it with the involved users, get a mod to help you. And that mod should decide for the greater good of the site, which in this case would be clearly to choose the proper tags, ultimately disagreeing with OP.

And yes, I believe that this situation is just the same as the xcode tag situation. It’s just the same principle. It just happens to be the case that the it has been a problem for the xcode tag for far longer and as a result is a lot more messy than the MVC tag or others. But that does not mean that we should allow using incorrect tags just because the tags themselves are less used so misuse is less of a problem. Otherwise, those tags will just become the new xcode tags in the future, and that solves really nothing.

Oh, and btw. comparing it with a [potato](/questions/tagged/potato) is a ridiculous comparison given that it’s not an existing tag and is absolutely off-topic. [mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc) though is—just like [xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode)—in general on-topic for SO, and also likely not too far off for most questions. But that does not mean that they are still appropriate tags for every question.

---

> 12,000 questions tagged MVC? Game over. [Robert Harvey♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220388/flag-helpful-but-no-action-taken-on-tag-war/220399#comment714455_220388)

So just because a tag is terribly over- and misused, that gives everyone the right to just use it incorrectly everywhere? You won’t be able to reduce that number if you don’t start somewhere and try to trim it down. I have to say, that such comments are rather disappointing to hear from moderators of this community. With that opinion, no wonder why the close queue isn’t going down either (but that’s a different topic).

Comment: I agree with most of this.  But I don't agree that "correctness is self-evident."  It's not.  In fact, tag scope is a hotly (and daily) debated topic on Meta, so you can't say with any certainty that any given tag usage is "obviously" correct.

Comment: Oh, and I think you missed the point about "potato."  Mods take action on things they need to take action on, and "potato" is clearly one of those things.

Comment: FWIW I think [tag:potato] is exactly as relevant to that question as [tag:mvc]. An architectural pattern is relevant to debugging a part in an (unrelated) API of a language as much as a vegetable. I do agree with Robert that mods can't be expected to know about all tag correctness issues - but then again the mod retagging the question didn't need or have to be the first action at all.

Comment: I don't think it is easy to determine if a tag usage is "obviously correct", but it is clear to see when they are not.

Comment: I don’t expect mods to be able to say if a tag is not correct. But when they are asked to review a dispute between users, I would assume that they should at least evaluate the situation. And from the history of the question, there were two established users independently agreeing with that the mvc tag was not appropriate. So that would be just *some* sign to me…

Answer (score 2):

One of the foundational principles of moderation is that *you shouldn't need detailed knowledge of the subject matter in order to successfully moderate.*

By asking a diamond moderator to evaluate a tag to see if it matches a question, you're asking for someone to make a determination based on domain knowledge.  Diamond mods don't do that; in general, we don't moderate *content* at all unless it is off-topic or abusive.

Comment: Thanks for adding an answer. To clarify - I did not expect (by any means) the flag to cause moderation of content. I flagged it because of the tag war and not because I wanted a mod to take 'my side' (even if I was correct technically) . I expected the flag to 1) clear the comments [it did, good!] 2) leave a comment on that question (or another form of guidance) on how to proceed. This is because while the tag itself wasn't an issue of moderation - the conduct in that tag war was.

Comment: I would probably have left a comment to the OP.  I doubt it would have changed his mind, though, and the only remaining option for a mod is to lock the question, which is a pretty blunt instrument.

Comment: isn't deleting it equally as blunt?

Comment: Ok, let's say OP disagrees. What would you do next? (and how would one get that question not to contain incorrect and misleading information implying OP was doing mvc if the answer to that is 'not intervene')

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I told you already; locking the question is the next step.

Comment: @rlemon: I don't know if you've read the question yet, but it was basically "How do I troubleshoot this code?" At the very least, it's too broad.  It might have stayed open, had the OP not attracted attention with the rollbacks, but it did close, and it already had 4 downvotes and a delete vote on it when I got here.  In short, nobody's going to miss it.  Deletion has the virtue of me (and everyone else) never having to look at it again.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ok, so back to my original question :) Let's say I'm in this situation again and my flag gets marked as helpful but OP still doesn't change the tag (and reverts it when a user with a high tag score re-tags it). What's my next step?

Comment: Nothing.  Move on.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I did read it. I agree the tag was invalid and I agree *something* should have been done.. however I just think that if you believe locking it was any less blunt than deleting it that the OP might feel different (I know I would).

Comment: I get the feeling that I'm being roped into a circular argument about semantics, so I'm going to bow out now.  If anyone (with 10K reputation) cares to take an *objective* look at the original question, I think you'll find that it's currently in a perfectly reasonable state.

Comment: There is no circular argument about semantics (at least from me). I was merely mentioning (how I feel) that the question being deleted was pretty harsh and that locking it would have sent a better message.