# Helpful migration flag, but no action

Tags: discussion, flags, migration

I cannot understand why my flag was marked as `helpful` if no action was taken on it.

I am talking about this flag on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4119617/1420197).

> [image]

It's `helpful` but no action was done on it.

Any explanation how flag was *helpful*?

Comment: @IanRingrose If it's a duplicate, what point from [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105395/205508) is fulfilled?

Comment: The middle bullet - you're kind of right, so it's a helpful flag, but the moderator decided not to take the action (because of the age of the post in this case)

Comment: @KateGregory You are right. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm no moderator, but I do know something about the migration system.

The question *does* belong on Code Golf, but there's a catch: **questions older than 60 days [cannot be migrated easily](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days)**.

This question is from 2010. Which is a long time ago. To migrate such a question, moderators have to make a list of all old questions they want migrated to another site, and give it to the CMs. Not worth it for one question.

Your flag is correct, but no action was taken.

Comment: Don't have the moderators this power? What do you mean when saying *cannot be migrated easily*?

Comment: @IonicăBizău Mods don't have that power. Only CMs can migrate old questions.

Comment: FWIW, I normally decline these flags with the reason "Too old to migrate."

Comment: @Undo *I'm no moderator* - maybe you will be soon. :-)