# How do 'useful' flags work?

Tags: support, flags

I flagged [a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/381417/is-it-should-be-run-or-should-be-ran-and-why) on [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com) as proofreading, (which it is).  I see later that it has been put on hold, but only by [Dan Bron](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/55623/dan-bron) and [tchrist♦](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2085/tchrist).

How do flags work?  I'm not trying to get a mention or any rep (not even sure if that happens), I'm just curious as to what would make an asker's flag be regarded as useful.  Is it because I flagged the question under a different category, or don't I have enough reputation?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites search page for "flags". See also http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts and the links therein.

Comment: I don't entirely understand... are you saying your flag wasn't marked as helpful? Or were you thinking that your name should have shown in the close notice?

Comment: @Cai both, actually.  Is this expected behaviour, or just an off-chance occurrence?

Comment: you have at least two questions. One is "[did / why did / why didn't ] my flag get marked helpful when the question was closed?" See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105391/why-does-flag-marking-as-helpful-declined-not-always-correlate-with-moderator-ac?noredirect=1&lq=1 The other is "why isn't my name in the list of closers?" and that list only shows those who **voted** to close, not those who flagged.

Comment: @KateGregory what's the difference? is this something I can't do with my sub 1k rep?

Comment: @marcellothearcane indeed, you can't cast actual close votes with 1k rep only, as the answer says. But you can still flag. That is the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of names in the post's close notice is only the users who *voted to close*, not users who *flagged*. Close voting is [a privilege that requires 3k rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) on graduated sites.

Flagging a question to be closed when you don't have the close vote privilege only places the post in to the [review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161390/307988) so that users with the relevant privileges can vote to close.

If a question that you flagged is subsequently closed then your flag should be marked as "helpful", but that doesn't publicly show anywhere; only in your flag history. You can see your flag history by clicking the "x helpful flags" link in [your profile](/users/current). If your flag was not marked as you expect then read: [Why does flag marking as helpful/declined not always correlate with moderator action?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105391/307988) and [What is a disputed flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95275/307988)